# Why can't Python separate the real and imaginary components of a complex number?

Tags: python

I am writing a code to solve a physics problem. To summarize, I have used the *solve* function to determine the roots of a quadratic, which are printed in a list that has 2 entries. I am extracting the first value (i.e. first entry of the list) and comparing it to the value of a randomly generated number (or more specifically, to the value of the function -ln(random #). The code indicates an error whenever the first entry of the list (first root) is complex (i.e. A + BI). Therefore, I was interested to see what will happen if I only consider the real part. I applied np.real(A + BI) and the return is still A + BI, which still causes the error. I have unsuccessfully tried a few ways to extract the real part only. Any advice? thanks in advance!

Here's part of the code:

```
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import Symbol
s = Symbol("s")
sol = solve((x_0+(omega_x*s)-x_c)**2+(y_0+(omega_y*s)-y_c)**2-9, s)
print("s = ", sol)

#"p" coordinates of intersection point with sphere
p = Symbol("p")
psol = solve((x_0+(omega_x*p)-x_d)**2+(y_0+(omega_y*p)-y_d)**2+(z_0+(omega_z*p)-z_d)**2-1, p)
print("p = ", psol)

#"s" regions
s_region1 = np.real(sol[0])
s_region2 = np.real(sol[1]) - np.real(sol[0])
s_region3 = np.real(psol[0]) - np.real(sol[1])
print("s_region1 = ", s_region1)
print("s_region2 = ", s_region2)
print("s_region3 = ", s_region3)

#Total number of mfp's in Region 1 and Region 2 (no scattering)
T1_ns = (s_region1 + s_region3)*sigma_1a
T2_ns = s_region2*sigma_2a
T_total_ns = T1_ns + T2_ns
print("T1_ns =", T1_ns)
print("T2_ns = ", T2_ns)
print("T_total_ns =", np.real(T_total_ns))

mfp[i] = (-1*np.log(np.random.random())) 
while (mfp[i] < T_total_ns):
    if np.random.random() > 1:
        mfp[i] = mfp[i] + (-1*np.log(np.random.random())) 
    else:
        break
else: 
    CountP = CountP + 1

Along with the corresponding error:
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-93-131a66cd0909> in <module>
152 
153     mfp[i] = (-1*np.log(np.random.random()))
--> 154     while (mfp[i] < T_total_ns):
155         if np.random.random() > 1:
156             mfp[i] = mfp[i] + (-1*np.log(np.random.random()))

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\expr.py in __gt__(self, other)
335         for me in (self, other):
336             if me.is_complex and me.is_real is False:
--> 337                 raise TypeError("Invalid comparison of complex %s" % me)
338             if me is S.NaN:
339                 raise TypeError("Invalid NaN comparison")

TypeError: Invalid comparison of complex 2.9397439170991 - 0.178627638621441*I
```

Comment: Hi Peter, tried running your code. Maybe I'm missing something but I'm not sure how you got this error. x_0, omega_x, x_c, y_0, omega_y and y_c are all undefined and undeclared. So this is a bit hard to recreate. mfp and CountP are uninitialized. If possible, try to include all appearing variables? Also, np.log(np.random.random() might crash your script if the random number is exactly 0. Lastly, for ease-of-debugging and reproducibility, you might want to use np.random.seed(somenumber)

Comment: Hi Ruslan, thanks for trying. I re-posted a working code here that captures the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61448225/why-cant-my-python-code-return-the-real-part-of-a-complex-number

Answer (score 0):

`np.real` does not modify the underlying value, it just returns the real part of a copy of the data. You only called `np.real` in the `print` function, but left the comparison untouched.

You need to modify the comparison itself:

```
while mfp[i] < np.real(T_total_ns):
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've tried several versions. In the one above, T_total_ns is a sum of terms on which np.real has been called, therefore it should be real. I also tried while mfp[i] < np.real(T_total_ns): and receive the same Invalid Comparison error. When I print out the value np.real(T_total_ns) I get T_total_ns = 3.12080881343374 - 0.214707557191093*I

Comment: @Peter Try to minimize your example to a piece of standalone code that still exhibits the issue. I just found the issue in the code you posted, with this change it shouldn't have the issue.

Comment: Good idea. I will try to re-post. Thank you.